# Java: Is there any difference in terms of memory management between using this.classVariable and classVariable in async callback?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

When we pass local variables to async callbacks we have to declare them final(well, they should be effectively final at least) all because Java cannot reference local variables and therefore it should do some "trick" to pass the copy of the local object to the inner class. On the other hand member variables do exists during the lifetime of the enclosing object, so they can be referenced by the inner class instance. So, since inner object can reference class variables of the outer object I have a question - will there be any differences in terms of memory management between these two code snippets
**Snippet 1**

```
SomeHttpLib.getData(new OnReponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    myClassVariable.doSomething()
                }
 })
```

**Snippet 2**

```
SomeHttpLib.getData(new OnReponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    MyClass.this.myClassVariable.doSomething()
                }
 })
```

The only difference between those two snippets is that the second one accesses `myClassVariable` via `this` ref, while the first one directly. So, it seems that the first example "captures" the reference to `myClassVariable` and prevents the object from being deallocated(or at least postpones the deallocation), but the outer object itself can be released! While the second example accesses `myLocalVariable` via `this` ref which makes the callback capture outer object and therefore prolonging its life ! So, am I reasoning in the right way, or I missed something ?
Please don't judge my question too hard, I'm just learning Java and trying to understand how the things are happening
Thank you
 Kind Regards,
Andre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, both snippets compile to exactly the same thing.

> So, it seems that the first example "captures" the reference to myClassVariable and prevents the object from being deallocated(or at least postpones the deallocation), but the outer object itself can be released!

That is not how it works.

`myClassVariable` is not captured separately, it will still refer to the field of the object (the outer `this`) and be resolved at the time the callback runs, so the whole object is being kept alive.

Only local variables are separately captured (and for this to work they need to be effectively `final`, because their value at the time the callback is created is captured, not a reference to them).